# Download file on device is blocking interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

Use this code for download file on my device. But on 99% loading interface stop(I can’t click on button). After 20 second everything works fine and loading = 100%. Why interface stop on 99% loading? How to fix it?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    _session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
        });

    [self.progressView setProgress:0 animated:NO];
}

- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender {
    if(_downloadTask == nil){

        _url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.nsw.gov.au/sites/default/files/bg-view-nsw-media.png"];

        _downloadTask = [_session downloadTaskWithURL:_url1];

        [_downloadTask resume];

    }

    else

    [_downloadTask resume];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image1.mp3"];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];


    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_url];
    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten  totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [ _progressView setProgress:totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpectedToWrite animated:YES];

    NSString *percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%", (int)((totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpectedToWrite)*100)];
    [_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%", percentage]];

    NSLog(@"%lld", totalBytesWritten);

    _label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(91, 15, 500, 50)];
    [_label setText: percentage];
    _label.numberOfLines = 1;
    _label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:_label];


    });
```

**UPD**

Then I remove this code

```
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_url];
    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **shouldn't** put *everything* in `main thread`. The only things to keep in `main thread` are `UI updates`.

Indeed, every action made in `main thread` will block the interface until the action finishes. What you want is having your download performing in `background`, and having **only** your `UI updates` in `main thread`.

What you have to do is following this code :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //Do background work
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Update UI
    });
});
```

For your case the code should look like :

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image1.mp3"];
        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];


        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_url];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this line [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; (and probably the one above) have to be call in background.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside of your

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /* code */ });
```

will be executed on main thread. In most cases you should avoid an execution of long processes there, because the ui (your button) can not respond until your task completes.

So try to use something like this for background downloads

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{ /* background download*/ });
```

and use your solution after the download completed to update your ui on main thread.